# Uploading image to facebook fan page fails

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When I try to upload an image to a fan page managed by me, it gets uploaded to my album instead of the fan page's album.

I've given the 'manage_page' permission [image: Permission Tab in Graph Explorer Tool]

And I've tried the following in the Graph Explorer Tool[image: Execution in Graph Explorer]

The id I've given is my page's id. I've tried changing that to the album id in the page also (the album is having can_upload set to true).

But still the image is getting uploaded to my profile rather than the page. Can someone please help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Finally I found the answer.

It seems there are two types of access_token. One is to manage the user and the other is to manage the page.

Normally the graph explorer shows the access_token to manage the user. To get the access_token to manage the page, we need to query that from "https://graph.facebook.com//accounts".

This would result like [image: Query Access Token for managing facebook]

Then, use that access_token to finally upload the image to your fan page as shown in pics in the question.

Hope this helps.